# In struct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Something baffles me about C++, I can write something like:

```
struct Test {
    double V[3];
}
```

without a problem, but when I try for e.g.:

```
struct Test {
    vector<double> V(3);
}
```

the compiler gives me an error. What is the difference between the above, I mean why can't the second one be compiled?

and, this one is even more baffling:

```
struct Test {
    std::vector<double> V[3];
}
```

The last example that at least in my mind should throw a compiler error is compiled without a problem by both GCC and Clang.

Comment: It seems like you want a fixed length array stl type.  If this is correct look into `std::array`

Comment: I don't want a fixed length array, I was just doing some exploratory coding and thought that this is an inconsistency in the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not confuse initialization and declaration.

```
double V[3];
```

This declares an array of three doubles. No problem. No initialization.

```
vector<double> V(3);
```

This declares a vector and tries to initialize it by calling its constructor with `3` as argument. Initialization like this is not allowed here. With C++11 you can use initialization syntax with curly braces, this is allowed:

```
vector<double> V{3};
```

However, since vector has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list<double>`, this will be interpreted as calling that constructor, not the one that takes a `size_t` value (the one you want). It will initialize the vector with a single element (`3.0`). You could use `V{0,0,0}` for what you want, though this might get ugly once you need more than 3 values.

Your final example

```
std::vector<double> V[3];
```

simply declares an array of three vectors. No initialization. No problem.

Comment: why is V(3) not allowed?

Comment: `V(3)` is not allowed because it's currently in a place that wants a type and a variable name and nothing else, such as `std::vector<double> V;`.  `V(3)` would be allowed in the constructor (or member initialzier list), where that variable needs to be initialized.

Comment: To clear any confusion, `vector<double> V{3};` does not do what the OP wants. It will create a vector with one element which value is the double 3.0.

Comment: Thanks SirDarius, I think gexicide meant: `vector<double> V{0, 0, 0};` which is the equivalent of `double V[3];` using `std::vector`.

Comment: @SirDarius: Righto, added that.

Comment: Or `vector<double> V = vector<double>(3);`, which will be much less ugly comparatively if you need 100 and not 3 elements. The grammar there requires a *brace-or-equal-initializer* because the parentheses version may cause ambiguities.

Answer (score 2):

Those are different things.

The first declares an array of three elements. The `[3]` is part of the type.

The second declares a vector, and then uses something that looks like initialization syntax, but isn't allowed in this particular context. The `(3)` is not part of the type. (Note that in C++11 or 14 you get in-class initializers that allow something similar.)

The third declares an array of three vectors. Compare the syntax to the first one: all that changes is that `double` is replaced by `std::vector<double>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is:

```
struct Test {
    vector<double> v;

    Test(): v(3) {}
};
```

which adds a constructor to your structure with an initialization list that explicitely invokes the vector's constructor with  `3` as a parameter.

It is otherwise not possible to call a constructor in the context of declaring structure or class members (excepting initializer lists constructors with the specific C++11 syntax using curly braces).

More generally, fixed-size arrays should use the `std::array` class, as mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I can't upvote you yet (not enough points here).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want a fixed length array stl type.  `std::vector` isn't this.  You're looking for `std::array`

You probably want `std::array<double, 3>`.

Please disregard if this isn't your intention.

Comment: Thanks, but I was simply trying to use a `std::vector` and not `std::array`.